# Multiples hyperlinks on the same page

Tags: html, spring-mvc, web, spring-security, frontend

I have been trying to set up two hyperlinks on the same page. For some reasons, regardless of the choice made by clicking on the hyperlinks, it always open the html page associated with the first option. Am I missing something?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">

<head>
  <title>Spring Security Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>Click <a th:href="@{/login}"> here </a>for login. </p>
  <p>Click <a th:href="@{/registration}"> here </a>to register as a new user.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is login.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" align="center" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" align="center" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The below is registration.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form th:action="@{/registration}" method="post">
         <div><label> Preferred User Name : <input type="text" align="center" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" align="center" name="pasisword"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Reentered password: <input type="password" align="center" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Address: <input type="text" align="center" name="address"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Upload Image : <input type="image" align="center" name="photos"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="new user"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

MvcConfig.java is as below.

```
    public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/registration").setViewName("registration");
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the rendered html from view-source please - the slash looks suspicious here `@{/login}`

Comment: You should add some tags specifically about the frontend framework you are using

Comment: Solved. The issue was with a security mechanism that I added for the app. The registration page should be allowed to be opened without any security check or login requirement. Later during the registration process, we can verify if the user is a genuine user or not, but the initial steps should not required anything.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

Split the string in the href

`@{'/' + ${login}}`

like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">

<head>
  <title>Spring Security Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>Click <a th:href="@{'/' + ${login}}"> here </a>for login. </p>
  <p>Click <a th:href="@{'/' + ${registration}}"> here </a>to register as a new user.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: or perhaps `"/@{login}"`